# How to make multiple events with Flask SocketIO?

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I have a socetio connection what provide search on button click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
socket.on('connect', function () {
            socket.emit('seatch event', {
                data: 'App Started'
            })
            var form = $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                let search_query = $('#search_text').val()
                socket.emit('search event', {
                    search_query: encodeURIComponent(search_query)
                })
            })
        });

socket.on('search_results_event', function (msg) {
    //do someting
});
```

Now i want to add another event, in my case i want to send data to server and recive answer each time when `<li>` element in list become `activate`.
How can i add this event?  I have to add another `connection`?
Any advises?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need another connection. Once the socket is connected, you can just use `socket.on` as you already have to catch events emitted from the server, and [emit](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) e.g. `socket.emit('[event_name], [data_object])` to send data to the server.

On the javacript side you emit like this

```
socket.emit('my_event', {'message': 'hello world'})
```

You can handle this on the `flask` side by

```
@socketio.on('my_event')
def handle_my_event(data):

    print('Received an instance of my_event')

    #  will print {'message': 'hello world'}
    print(data)
```

Similarly you can emit events from the `flask` server, such as your `search_results_event` by

```
from flask_socketio import emit

emit('search_results_event', {'key': 'value'})
```

Which would be handled by your existing `socket.on` in the question. The second argument to `emit` is the data you want to send - usually json.

See [the docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more information.